# access lable on main asp page from class

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a lable I want to update on a web form page from another class. I created an instance of that class then referenced a public method to do the update since I was unable to access the lable control directly. But when it reaches the public method it seems as if the controls were initialized and are not recognizable.

```
*...' calling class*
dim kws as new form2class
kws.setErrorLable("ERROR FOUND" & ex.message.tostring)
.....
```

called class

```
 public sub serrorLable(Byval msg as string)

 label10.text=msg

  end sub
```

Am I missing something here? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the current page like this:

```
Page currentPage = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
```

Depending on where the label is in the page, you may need to use recursion to find the Label, but the above code will get you to the current page.

Comment: brilliant, thanks...got the right page, found the control and all's well